# C++ erase-remove type deduction failed

Tags: c++

I have

```
auto foo = [](FooPtr p) {return p->m_delete;};
std::deque<FooPtr> d = getD();
d.erase(std::remove(d.begin(), d.end(), foo), d.end());
```

and I get a massive list of compile errors for template argument deduction/substitution failed:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_deque.h:258:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/predefined_ops.h:191:17: note:   'std::shared_ptr<Foo>' is not derived from 'const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>'
{ return *__it == _M_value; }

/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/predefined_ops.h:191:17: note:   'std::shared_ptr<Foo>' is not derived from 'const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>'

/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/predefined_ops.h:191:17: note:   'std::shared_ptr<Foo>' is not derived from 'const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>'
{ return *__it == _M_value; }
```

This list goes on for a long time. Any idea what I am doing wrong with my erase-remove?

Comment: `d` is a pointer so `d->erase(...` no?

Comment: `d.erase` -> hint: `d` is a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, typo. d was a pointer, but I made some changes since I thought that could have been an issue. it was not

Comment: Can you please give us a [mcve]?

Comment: what seemed to have fixed the compile error is using remove_if instead of remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong algorithm.  `std::remove()` expects a value - a FooPtr -  you should use `std::remove_if()` to specify a predicate.

Check the documentation at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove